# Exponential map is diffeomorphism on a neighborhood in TM

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold and let $TM$ be the tangent bundle. For each $p \in M$, it is known that there is a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $(p,0)$ in $TM$ such that the exponential map $exp: \mathcal{U} \rightarrow M$ is well-defined and smooth on $\mathcal{U}$.

**My question**: is it possible to find a neighbourhood $\mathcal{V}$ of $(p,0)$ in $TM$ such that $exp: \mathcal{V} \rightarrow M$ is diffeomorphism?

It is also known that if we only stick to $T_{p}(M)$, which is a subspace of $TM$, then we can find a neighbourhood $\mathcal{W}$ of $0$ in $T_{p}(M)$ such that $exp: \mathcal{W} \rightarrow M$ is differomorphism. The difference here in my question is that the neighborhood $\mathcal{V}$  contains vectors in different tangent spaces, not only in $T_{p}(M)$.

Thank.

Comment: $\mathscr{V}$ is an open set in a $2n$-dimensional manifold,  is a $n$-dimensional manifold, so there can't be a diffeomorphism

Comment: That's a very beautiful answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always possible to find such a neighborhood. Suppose that $M=S^1$, it is not possible to find an a neighborhood diffeomorphic to $S^1$, since such a neighborhood is a connected interval, which is open or has a boundary.